# After slicing some values from the edges, how to put the remaining values in exactly the same bins of histogram where they were before slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In the following code I have sliced first and last 5 values from array a. Now I want to plot a new histogram in which values of b should be exactly in the same bins where they were. How can I do that? After slicing the information that a value belongs to a certain bin is completely lost and also the if I plot new histogram after slicing values the the bin counts will change that is the main problem.

```
`a = np.sort(np.array([1,3,5,6,10,0,0,0,0,49,49,49,70,100,0,0,0]))
print(a)
n,bins,hist = plt.hist(a,bins=10)
print(n)     #[11.  1.  0.  0.  3.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
b=a[5:-5]
print(b)`     #[ 0  0  1  3  5  6 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the bins you want when plotting the second histogram. So take the generated bins from using vector a, and use them to plot histogram b

```
a = np.sort(np.array([1,3,5,6,10,0,0,0,0,49,49,49,70,100,0,0,0]))
print(a)
n,bins,hist = plt.hist(a,bins=10)
b=a[5:-5]
new_count, new_bins, new_hist = plt.hist(b,bins=bins)
```